# How to update a Preference with a SummaryProvider in a PreferenceFragmentCompat?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

In `androidx.preference.Preference` (using Version 1.1.0-beta01) it is possible to set a summary provider, which I did inside the `onCreatePreferences` method of a `PreferenceFragmentCompat`.

```
override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
  ...

  val mySummaryProvider = Preference.SummaryProvider<Preference> {
     val str = preferenceManager.sharedPreferences.getString(it.key, "")
     doSomethingCool(str)
  }

  findPreference<Preference>("my_pref_id").summaryProvider = mySummarProvider
}
```

When I now update the preference (by using the preference editor) while the fragment is still visible, how do I notify the preference or the fragment that the summary provider should be called again (it isn't done automatically)? Unfortunately, I don't see any method or way to do that.

Answer (score 4):

```
    public class SettingsClass extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
        @Override
        public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings_prefs);

            final SwitchPreferenceCompat switchPreferenceCompat = (SwitchPreferenceCompat) getPreferenceManager().findPreference("rememberME");
            switchPreferenceCompat.setSummaryProvider(new Preference.SummaryProvider() {
                @Override
                public CharSequence provideSummary(Preference preference) {
                    if (switchPreferenceCompat.isChecked()) {
                        return "Active";
                    }
                    return "Inactive";


                }
            });
    }}

//.xml file
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:key="test">
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Σύνδεση">
    <SwitchPreferenceCompat
        app:key="rememberME"
        android:defaultValue="false"
        app:title="Παραμείνετε Συνδεδεμένος" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 2):

`SummaryProvider` is mostly intended to be used for updating the summary of a preference after it updates itself, such as when an option in a `ListPreference` is selected, forcing an update of the `Preference` and hence triggering the `SummaryProvider`.

If you are typically changing the data underneath the preference, do you need a `SummaryProvider` here? If not, you could  just manually call `setSummary` when you change the data, since `Preferences` currently don't observe their backing data source. It's hard to tell without more sample code, but it seems strange that the data can change without the user's input, while they are currently viewing the preferences.

Comment: In my case, I have a preference that opens a system dialog (by using an intent) to select a ringtone (which is set in onActivityResult of the settings fragment). So the specific setting is changed in the background. In the end, I followed your second suggestion and switched over to `setSummary` in a preference change listener. But I still think that `SummaryProvider` would be nicer if only a way to notify of updates would be supported.

Answer (score 0):

I am having a bit trouble to understand the issue, but I would use setSummaryProvider only to update the summary and use a ChangeListener to update other stuff:

```
        with(findPreference<ListPreference>(PREFKEY_DOWNLOAD_SERVER)!!) {
            setSummaryProvider { pref ->
                getString(R.string.pref_download_server_summary, (pref as ListPreference).value)
            }
            setOnPreferenceChangeListener { _, newValue -> DataLoader.setSelectedServer(newValue as String); true }
        }
```